# How to wrap HTML/PHP concatenation in Wordpress Function

Tags: wordpress

I'm making my first basic Wordpress Theme, and trying to create a function to retrieve and display the first 6 posts, which I could use in various areas depending on the page you're on. It is very similar to [this tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-random-posts-in-wordpress/#respond), that I found... after facing the fact it doesn't work in my theme. 
Here is a simplified piece of the code (I tried several versions) :

```
function show_last_items() {
 while ( have_posts() && $count < 6) : 
  the_post();  
  $count++;
  print '<article id="post-'.the_ID().'" class="post-link-display">
            <a href="'.the_permalink().'" title="'.the_title_attribute().'">
                <div class="date">
                    <p>'.the_time( 'd/m' ).'</p>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                    <h6>'.the_title().'</h6>
                </div>
            </a>
        </article>';
 endwhile;
}
```

For some reason, while the code inside the function works just fine if I use it directly on a template part (for example sidebar.php), all the HTML seems to be wiped off when used as a function...  Or more exactly, it still exists, but in-between the data. So I get something like this displayed :

> 55http://localhost/myTheme/posts/55/my-post-title/My post title19/03My
>   post title
>
> 56http://localhost/myTheme/posts/56/my-other-post-title/My other post
>   title19/03My other post title

Yet the `<article>` tag and every markup in it is still there, empty, after each line that displays the retrieved information. I'd really like to understand why the concatenation doesn't work properly in this case. Is it something about the theme support ? It doesn't seem to me the WP_Widget class would change anything to this issue, but maybe I'm wrong ?

Comment: you might need to access global post -

Comment: This is it, problem solved. It points out the critical oversight I was making in my template. I'll update my question with details so that beginners like me can avoid it. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function show_last_items() {
 while ( have_posts() && $count < 6) : 
  the_post();  
  $count++;
  sprintf('<article id="post-%s" class="post-link-display">
            <a href="%s" title="%s">
                <div class="date">
                    <p>%s</p>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                    <h6>%s</h6>
                </div>
            </a>
        </article>', the_ID(), the_permalink(), the_title_attribute(), the_time( 'd/m' ), the_title());
}
```

Comment: Although this is cleaner, it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried building a string and then returning it?

```
$return_string = '';

// while loop

$return_string .= '<article .....';

// end while

return $return_string;
```

Comment: Yes I did, with the exact same result.

Comment: @AlexKouteynikoff Have you tried it using the get_the_title(), get_the_id(), get_the_permalink() etc. functions?